# How to access dom elements of #document from embed tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, embed

I have an markup with embed tag want to access **#document** contents.

[image]

Tried to traverse till embed tag after fetching couldn't able to access inner nodes however there is an function available **getElementByTagName()** or **getElementByClassName()** but it not helped

```
var embedContent = document.getElementById('embed1')
var parentContents = x.parentElement.parentNode.lastElementChild.getElementsByTagName('embed')
> [function, embed1: function]
```

Below able to access embed tag after this how to fetch values of respective tag

[image]

[image]

Is there alternate way to achieve this??If yes please provide any url or examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content of an `<embed>` tag is essentially locked Shadow DOM - it's a whole new document that Chrome can access but you can't.

It's easy to check what properties you can access:

```js
var xObj = document.getElementById('xObj');

for (var p in xObj) {
  var value = null;
  try {
    value = xObj[p];
  } catch (err) {}

  if (value)
    console.log(p, value);
}
```

```html
<embed id="xObj" src="http://stackoverflow.com"> </embed>
```

Your best bet to actually get the HTML is to load that content yourself:

```
var response = await fetch(document.getElementById('embedTag').src);
```

Comment: Okay,Is there any way to just access markup of other website, i tried iframe due to same origin possible so i moved to embed tag here also not possible.if you aware of any other possible way share here @Keith

Comment: @rselvaganesh Anything you find that circumvents same origin policy would be a security bug and likely to be patched pretty quickly.