# How to get data received from embed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<embed src=https://example.com></embed>
<script>
alert(embed data)
</script>
```

How to get data received from embed in javascript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access dom elements of #document from embed tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610519/how-to-access-dom-elements-of-document-from-embed-tag)

Answer (score 0):

add id to eht element and then use javascript to get the data like that

```
<embed id="embed" src=https://example.com></embed>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById("embed").src)
</script>
```

Comment: I need not a link, but the data inside the tag.